# In Python BeautifulSoup4, How to extract the special text like this

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some string. from this text:

```
    text = "<li>(<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.icd9data.com/getICD9Code.ashx?
    icd9=999.1">999.1</a>) <a href="/wiki/Air_embolism" title="Air embolism">Air embolism</a> as
    a complication of medical care not elsewhere classified</li>"
```

My target is the "as a complication of medical care not elsewhere classified" 
But the syntax doesn't work:

```
    soup = bs4.Beautifulsoup(text)
    for tag in soup.find_all('li'):
        print tag.string
```

Any body know any method can call the string I want?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for tag in soup.find_all('li'):
    print(tag.get_text())
```

prints

```
(999.1) Air embolism as
a complication of medical care not elsewhere classified
```

The `get_text` method returns all the text in a tag, even that text which is part of subtags.

---

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/), you could use

```
import lxml.html as LH
text = """<li>(<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.icd9data.com/getICD9Code.ashx?
icd9=999.1">999.1</a>) <a href="/wiki/Air_embolism" title="Air embolism">Air embolism</a> as
a complication of medical care not elsewhere classified</li>"""

doc = LH.fromstring(text)
for tag in doc.xpath('//li/a[2]'):
    print(tag.tail)
```

to obtain

```
 as
a complication of medical care not elsewhere classified
```